# Show VectorLayer in window

Tags: pyqgis

I'm new in PyQgis.
I can create vector layer and lines/polygons on it :

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "points", "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
pt = QgsFeature()
point1 = QgsPoint(0,0)
point2 = QgsPoint(100,100)
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([point1,point2]))
pr.addFeatures([pt])
layer.updateExtents()
```

Is there a simple way, how can I visuall see that line in window?

I tried canvas, but I wasn't able to display anything on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the second line in my code:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "points", "memory")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
pr = layer.dataProvider()
pt = QgsFeature()
point1 = QgsPoint(0,0)
point2 = QgsPoint(100,100)
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([point1,point2]))
pr.addFeatures([pt])
layer.updateExtents()
```

The result is in the next image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I had that line, but after that code I posted.